# Google Analytics: How to find URLs of paths that are (not set)?

Tags: google-analytics, url, referrer

We're getting a lot hits that have page title set to (not set). For example, on "Pages and Screens: Page Title and Screen Class", we get:

[image: (not set) page title example]

We don't know where they're stemming from. How can we some (/all) URL paths of events that generated these page titles?

Comment: I am not following it, could you clarify with examples perhaps ?

Comment: @RohitGupta Yes ofc, edited my question!

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is: you can't get the page path.

(not set) will happen when page_view is not fired when the event occurred. In that case, you won't have page path either. The user could have had the page already open in a browser.

Do some more digging by:

1. Click the blue + and add Landing page + query string. See where they are going.
2. Scroll over to Event Count and select different events to filter on and see if you have a pattern there.

With a little investigating, you might figure it out.

Comment: What do you mean with "page_view is not fired when the even occurred"? Another event was triggered before "page_view" was triggered?

Comment: I figured it out - i had to click the blue +, but then select page path. The path was luckily recorded. If you want to edit your answer to include that information, I'll accept it, otherwise I'll post my own answer :)